# basic HTTP POST example

Tags: javascript, php

i have three code files that are supposed to return a pressed character but they don't. quite new to http can someone spot my mistake?
(all three files were in the same directory)

httpgetexample.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body style="background-color: darkgreen">

<input type="text" id="name"></input>
<div id="name_feedback"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jfunc.js"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

jfunc.js

```
]$('#name').keyup(function(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    $.post('process_name.php',{name: name}, function(data){
        $('#name_feedback').html(data);
    });
});
```

process_name.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo strrev($name);
    }
?>
```

Comment: The `]` at the beginning of your JS is not supposed to be there - but perhaps you made a mistake with copying?

Comment: There is no error except `]` may be typo, make sure that you have uploaded files on server, and there no cross domain issue with ajax, if you are opening htm file on browser something like `file:///path/to/htm`, then you will not get any response.

Comment: What error do you get from your network?